# Why does string concatenation consume only the first string?

Tags: rust

I was reading [rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-02-strings.html#concatenation-with-the--operator-or-the-format-macro) when I came across this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("Hello, ");
    let s2 = String::from("world!");
    let s3 = s1 + &s2; // note s1 has been moved here and can no longer be used
}
```

as it turns out 'The `+` operator uses the `add` method, whose signature looks something like this':

```rust
fn add(self, s: &str) -> String { // ... }
```

I understand the reason why `s1` is 'consumed' and is no longer available later. But why does rust do this? I mean, why can't `add` method have reference to self (`&self`) as a first parameter, so that `s1` string will be available for later use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the signature was `fn add(&self, s:&str)` this would mean that, even if in the calling context the first parameter (known as `self`) could be consumed (because not used any more afterwards), the `add()` function would **have to** start by cloning this string in order to extend it with `s`.

On the other hand, using a **value** for `self` enables the reuse of the original string to extend it directly without cloning.

This situation is at the same time the most efficient and the most general because if you really want to preserve the original string you can always clone it before the call to `add()`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("Hello, ");
    let s2 = String::from("world!");
    let s3 = s1 + &s2;
    // println!("s1: {}", s1); // borrow of moved value: `s1`
    println!("s2: {}", s2);
    println!("s3: {}", s3);
    println!("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    let s1 = String::from("Hello, ");
    let s2 = String::from("world!");
    let s3 = s1.clone() + &s2;
    println!("s1: {}", s1); // not consumed by +
    println!("s2: {}", s2);
    println!("s3: {}", s3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.